# Need help to understand result set from PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following function executing PDO queries:

```
  // removed error handling for presenting here
  function getRows($sql) {
      $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          
      return $result;            
    } 
  }
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category] => Audi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category] => BMW
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category] => Chrysler
        )

)
```

The the following `foreach` code:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value ) {
  echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```

outputs this:

```
Array
Array
Array
```

What can I do so it returns the following?

```
Audi
BMW
Chrysler
```

I understand that I could just do `$value['category]`.

But that's not what I want to achieve / understand. I would like the resultset **not** to be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foreach($result as $key => $value ) {
  echo $value['category'].'<br/>';
}
```

#### Alternative

```
foreach($result as $k)
{
    echo $k['category'];
}
```

Comment: I know, but that is not what I want. I want the `$value` to be the value, not an array.

Comment: @Steven why u need so??? if something really valid then change the fetch style `fetchAll(PDO::fetch_style`)

Comment: Because, for me, it makes things a tiny bit simpler :) But it looks like creating a custom `fetch_style` is the only way to achieve my goal.

Comment: I'm currently doing what you are suggestion now. I just thought there might be some other way. But I'm getting the point now :)

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop splits up your array into key, value pairs. The key in your loop is the index of the array, the value is an array containing ID and Category.

To access the category simply do:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value ) {
  echo $value['category'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I understand that. See my update. Is there a way to avoid PDO returning an array of arrays?

Comment: Try selecting only the category in your query and not id + category.